# When you are devoid of questioning and answering on this site.

Tags: support

Due to some serious misery I will not be able to participate in questioning and answering on this site regularly or would do rarely (perhaps one question answer activity in ten days) as far as I can see.So can community of this site ban me for posting questions and answers on the ground of being inactive for long?Or is also possible that one day my account will be deleted due to being lazy?

Comment: It is not quite clear what you are asking, really.

Comment: I had tried to make all the possible effort to make this question understandable.What are you not getting please tell me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your account will continue to exist independently of how often you show up.

Comment: And what about being devoid of question answer activity by community?I mean you cant put questions and cant give answer.Can the community ban me for this kind of laziness in question answer activity?

Comment: Again, I do not understand what you are asking. But as I said, your account will not be removed for any absence of yours, ever.

Comment: I am really frightened and need help.May be that I am irritating you but somewhere I read that if you don`t participate in question and answer activity regularly then one day you will be banned by the community to post questions and answers further.

Comment: I have told you twice already that **nothing will happen yo your account even if you stop participating for a while, even a long time**. If you read otherwise, then the soruce was wrong.

Comment: Wait, but doesn't your account get deleted after a certain amount of inactivity? I have read this also, and am also seriously frightened!